# Como agrupar datos de una lista de listas si se repite el mismo valor en la primera posición de la sublista

Tags: python, arraylist

llevo días tratando de agrupar datos que están en una lista de listas y la condición que hace que estos se agrupen que es sea el mismo email:

list_the_lists:[('juanpa10oct@gmail.com', 'gasesdeoriente', '890503900-2'), ('juanpa10oct@yahoo.com', 'Institucion Universitaria Digital de Antioquia', '901168222-9'), ('juanpam10@hotmail.com', 'ALCALDIA DE SANTA ROSA DE CABAL', '891480033-4'), ('juanpam10@hotmail.com', 'DIRECCION GENERAL MARITIMA', '830027904-1')]

necesito que la información quede en algún lado de tal manera:

resultado= [('juanpam10@hotmail.com','DIRECCION GENERAL MARITIMA', '830027904-1','ALCALDIA DE SANTA ROSA DE CABAL', '891480033-4')

de momento e intentado con este bucle pero no se en que estoy errando :

```
matches = []
for largoI in range(len(i )):
    for j in range(largoI,len(i)):
        for x in i[largoI]:
            if x in destinatarios:
                matches=(set(x[0],x[1:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matches = []

def buscaBusca( list_the_lists ):                
    for i in range( len( list_the_lists )):
        guarda = True
        for k in range( len( matches )):
            if list_the_lists[ i ][ 0 ] == matches[ k ][ 0 ]:
                matches[ k ] = matches[ k ] + ( list_the_lists[ i ][ 1 ],  list_the_lists[ i ][ 2 ] )
                guarda = False
        if guarda:
            matches.append( list_the_lists[ i ] )
         
 
            
buscaBusca( list_the_lists )    
print( matches )
```

Una forma de conseguir lo que necesitas es con el ejemplo anterior.
Con el `for` externo recorremos la lista de datos.
Con el interno, recorremos la lista de salida, si encontramos coincidencia del campo correo, entramos al `if`, donde concatenamos el contenido de **matches** con los datos de **list_the_lists**, si el ciclo se completa sin coincidencias, se entra en el segundo `if` y se agrega todo el contenido de **list_the_lists[ i ]**.